# Image on start up / loading

Tags: android, image, loading, oncreate

I ma developing an app, which at the moment when it is loading from the onCreate point, I just have a black screen (until the app gets its footing). Looking at other apps they have a company logo or cool image that pops up for a few seconds, can someone tell me how to do this please?

And if you can set it to display for a minimal time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a new activity that displays the image for a few seconds and redirects to your main activity:

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity
{
    private static final long DELAY = 3000;
    private boolean scheduled = false;
    private Timer splashTimer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        splashTimer = new Timer();
        splashTimer.schedule(new TimerTask()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                SplashActivity.this.finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
         }, DELAY);
       scheduled = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (scheduled)
            splashTimer.cancel();
        splashTimer.purge();
    }
}
```

Set your image as the background for this activity. Hope that helps. Good luck!

Comment: But please use `Handler` instead of `TimerTask`.

Comment: Did you test this code on emulator or real device? There's NO `Timer` on Android!

Comment: Timer is not an android object, its a java object. It is a working code in one of my apps. It works on both a device and an emulator. Add the following to your import list and you will be fine:

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

Comment: Delaying an app start is never a good policy. This [link](https://android.jlelse.eu/the-complete-android-splash-screen-guide-c7db82bce565) shows an article that explains how to properly do it. The core idea is to load an image while the app is doing the initial processing.

Answer (score 1):

This start up image also known as 'splash screen'. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979524/android-splashscreen) you can find how to make splash screen.

Answer (score 0):

Your needs is callign Splash Screen. Here is my splash screen code.

Just add new activity and set application for opening this activity.

public class SplashActivity extends DeviceInfoAbstractActivity {

```
@SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, R.layout.activity_splash);

    passScreen();
}

private void passScreen() {

    new CountDownTimer(1000, 2000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            Intent intent = RDAIntentHelpers.getClearCacheIntent();

            intent.setClass(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }.start();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //no exit
}
}
```

and this my getClearCacheIntent() method

```
public static Intent getClearCacheIntent() {

    Intent intent = new Intent();

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

    return intent;
}
```

after these, your splash screen stays on screen for 2 seconds. Do whatever you want =)